# Escape is causing issues

Tags: ce-cache

I have the following code:

```
{exp:ce_cache:escape:last_updated}
{if ({current_time format="%U"} - {edit_date format="%U"})/3600 < 8}Updated {edit_date:relative}{/if}
{/exp:ce_cache:escape:last_updated}
```

This code displays a text on how old an entry is for the first 8 hours.
But it does not escape the caching. When placing the escape around the {edit_date:relative} it does not generate the time, only text.

Please help out if you can.

Best regards,
Harold

Comment: I would suggest not caching this line to begin with. Performing a numerical date comparison is quick work. However, you can try using a nested template where the nested template contains your inner logic and the ce_cache:escape wraps the template include.